# Avoid escaping of characters when converting JSON to XML

Tags: python, json, xml, encoding, escaping

Is there a way in python to modify my JSON in a way that when I send JSON input to my SOAP api which converts the data to XML, then the json data is not escaped.

This is JSON data:

```
{'test1': [{'entityClass': '', 'entityMode': 'Q', 'Mgr2': '', 'Mgr3': '', 'Mgr1': '', 'Recid': 0, 'CSRCode': '', }, {'entityClass': '', 'entityMode': 'Q', 'Mgr2': '', 'Mgr3': '', 'Mgr1': '', 'Recid': 0, 'CSRCode': ''}]}
```

I'm passing these arguments to the Suds library, to call the SOAP api.

When these are passed to soap api which converts it to XML, this becomes:

```
<TblJSONData>{&apos;tblw&apos;: [{&apos;CSRClass&apos;: &apos;&apos;, &apos;Mode&apos;: &apos;Q&apos;, &apos;EscMgr2&apos;: &apos;&apos;, &apos;EscMgr3&apos;: &apos;&apos;, &apos;EscMgr1&apos;: &apos;&apos;, &apos;EntityRecid&apos;: 0, &apos;CSRCode&apos;: &apos;11945&apos;, &apos;Entity&apos;: &apos;&apos;, &apos;RC&apos;: 0, &apos;ErrMsg&apos;: &apos;&apos;, &apos;EntityCount&apos;: 0}, {&apos;CSRClass&apos;: &apos;&apos;, &apos;Mode&apos;: &apos;Q&apos;, &apos;EscMgr2&apos;: &apos;&apos;, &apos;EscMgr3&apos;: &apos;&apos;, &apos;EscMgr1&apos;: &apos;&apos;, &apos;EntityRecid&apos;: 0, &apos;CSRCode&apos;: &apos;96456&apos;, &apos;Entity&apos;: &apos;&apos;, &apos;RC&apos;: 0, &apos;ErrMsg&apos;: &apos;&apos;, &apos;EntityCount&apos;: 0}, {&apos;CSRClass&apos;: &apos;&apos;, &apos;Mode&apos;: &apos;Q&apos;, &apos;EscMgr2&apos;: &apos;&apos;, &apos;EscMgr3&apos;: &apos;&apos;, &apos;EscMgr1&apos;: &apos;&apos;, &apos;EntityRecid&apos;: 0, &apos;CSRCode&apos;: &apos;65844&apos;, &apos;Entity&apos;: &apos;&apos;, &apos;RC&apos;: 0, &apos;ErrMsg&apos;: &apos;&apos;, &apos;EntityCount&apos;: 0}]}<TblJSONData>
```

Is there a way to modify JSON, so that when it is converted to xml it is not escaped.

Any help in this would be great.

Comment: It look like a problem on SOAP api side, not json encoding

Comment: Please add the commands you're using to generate the XML, so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @user3286912 how you send json? could you add example?

Comment: I'm passing the arguments to the Suds library, which calls the soap api. __call__ function in Suds library is making the actual call to soap api. Is there a way that I can modify the xml here somehow ?

Comment: I have imported Method from suds.client & using it to call the soap api the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing to do with the JSON end of things, it's a question of choosing an XML serializer that doesn't escape apostrophes. I don't know what's available in the Python world, but most XML tools if asked to parse this XML with the `&apos;` references, and then re-serialize it, will output the apostrophes "as is" without escaping.